# Where can a tourist to Malta ride an articulated bus?

Tags: public-transport, buses, malta, nostalgia

I was thinking a short break to Valletta might be enhanced by taking one of the ['bendy buses' that used to serve London](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Articulated_buses_in_London).

Is it possible to ride one of these?  Or alternatively, are there any bus routes in London that are still served by bendy buses?  If not, then where would I have to go to ride one?

Comment: As a more distant option, San Francisco's MUNI system operates articulated buses.  I'm sure there are many many more.

Comment: FYI, there are a few in Genoa, Italy, too.

Comment: And Denver and a lot of places.

Comment: I find it really amusing that something as common as a bendy bus would be considered an attraction :-)

Comment: @Szabolcs, sadly, there is no 'nostalgia' tag

Comment: @GayotFow Create it. ;)

Comment: @JoErNanO, DDGF -> http://www.odps.org/glossword/index.php?a=term&d=4&t=3638

Comment: Articulated buses are still used in many U.S. cities, where the roads are more easily able to accommodate them. I rode one to and from school in the 1980s, usually taking one of the seats right in the joint. If you find yourself on that side of the pond, you might seek one out.

Comment: Articulated busses are more than commonplace in many European cities, urban areas and even beyond. Even in places with narrow and winding streets such as Lausanne or Luxembourg you will find them. You even find more and more XXL variants such as bi-articulated busses or the Mercedes CapaCity.

Comment: You even find them with different propulsions: Diesel, Gas, hybrid, electric.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The buses that London sold to Malta are unfortunately, no longer in Malta.

All 80 Mercedes buses have been [exported to Sudan](http://www.timesofmalta.com/articles/view/20140218/local/bendy-buses-to-be-shipped-to-sudan.507334) after they caused congestion, caught fire and were generally disliked, it seems.

Indeed, the article notes, in addition to the fires:

> In offering the buses for sale, Transport Malta had laid down that
>   they cannot be returned to Malta’s roads, because of the congestion
>   they caused.

[None of the bendy buses operate any longer in London](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Articulated_buses_in_London#Withdrawal), however they were moved around the UK in addition to Malta:

> Withdrawn buses have found their way to other parts of the UK. Some
>   went to Arriva Midlands in Leicester and Arriva North West in
>   Liverpool. Go-Ahead Group transferred some to their Brighton & Hove,
>   Go North East, Southern Vectis and Wilts & Dorset operations. Some
>   were sold to CT Plus, Bristol and McGill's Bus Services, Glasgow

And indeed, the Wiki article on [their use in the UK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Articulated_buses_in_the_United_Kingdom#Modern_era) shows that they're still operating in Cardiff, among other places.

Answer (score 5):

There are no more bendy buses on Malta's roads, but they have NOT been exported to Sudan in the end... They are, in fact, rotting in a yard in [San Gwann](https://maps.app.goo.gl/HLgfy1XwYEB2Fnpp8) (next to the road to Naxxar). If you want to "experience" a bendy bus, you could come to Innsbruck, Austria. Here they are something totally normal :)

Comment: Or Vienna, or Klagenfurt, or...

Comment: Or the Netherlands, Amsterdam for instance but all around the country they can be found on busy routes.

Comment: Same in germany, whenever there are times with more passengers expected they get used

Comment: Or Romania, where not only do they have bendy buses, but they even have [_electric_ bendy-buses](https://produsinardeal.ro/2020/02/10/municipiul-brasov-a-luat-16-mil-euro-de-la-ue-pentru-achizitia-a-35-de-troleibuze-si-autobuze-noi/) which run on long arms connected to overhead wires, so that when going around a bend, you can occasionally have the entertaining experience of watching an arm stray off a wire, whereupon the bus dies and the driver has to go get off the bus, go around back, and reseat the arm.

Comment: Articulated buses are common across ALL Europe, except for the UK. Just about every city over 50k inhabitants (or even less) uses them for public transport.

Comment: @Kyralessa Those are called *trolleybuses* and are also common in Europe, mainly Central Europe and ex-Soviet countries. :-) Some cities even operate extra long buses and trolleybuses with two articulations. These are still quite rare and could be a tourist attraction.

Comment: Yes, _troleibuz_ in Romanian.